# EU law regarding delivery location of online purchases

Tags: european-union, consumer-protection, sweden

There is EU law regarding delivery of online purchases but I am struggling to find the specific section regarding the physical location to which it is acceptable to deliver to.

My experience is that that in Sweden it is very common to deliver to a local deposit point, usually within walking distance if in a city and that point has reasonable opening hours.

In the case of a recent delivery the company has shipped a package to me, for which it has charged a substantial sum for delivery to a local warehouse, but has delivered it to a warehouse 4.5km away, with collection hours only on weekdays between 10am and 16pm.

With other provides (DHL, UPS, Postnord) the package would be delivered within a few 100 metres with a much broader set of collection times.

Is there anything that would legally state this is an unreasonable attempt to devolve the company of their delivery responsibility?

What is my recourse?

Comment: Was there anything in the terms of sale regarding delivery?

Comment: I would assume it common sense that a "delivery" is to my doorstep. If I have to go and pick it up, that does not fit the common sense of the word "delivery". I have no idea of Swedish laws or customs, so not an answer, just a comment.

Comment: I can't answer your question about delivery law but an alternative 'recourse' is that you have a 14 day cooling off period. You can return - or in your case have someone return - the product for any reason.